# Turn base64 Response into PDF

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, base64

Let me start by saying I am pretty new to the development world. I am working on a project to create a PDF on a button click.

I managed to set up the back end using `Node.js` and got the response in my front end as a base64 object after I used `JSON.Parse()`:

Response from server:

[image: image - response from server].

My question is how do I get that response to be a PDF that opens up in a new tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that Node serve a pdf file directly you have to create a pdf file with node and serve it from your service. Tools you might want to use for this are
pdfkit and express.js (for the webserver)

pdfkit: http://pdfkit.org/

If you want to serve the pdf from a clientapp you could use jsPDF for this. https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Here an example how to add an image:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,YOUR_BASE64STR_HERE');
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
```

Answer (score 2):

With an anchor:

```
<a download="Title" href="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xL...." title='Download pdf document' />
```

In a new Tab

```
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0x..");
```